# Multiple <input> functions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this code : http://jsfiddle.net/eYgdm/345/

```
<label for="check" class="btn btn-default">Toggle background colour</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.test1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #5CB85C;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1;
}
.test2 {
    position:absolute;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    top:100px;
    z-index:2;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
label.btn {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index:2;
    user-select: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + test1 {
    background: #5BC0DE;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + test2 {
    background: #000000;
}
label + input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background: #000;
}
```

I want when the button is checked to change test1 and test2 background. But it used to work only for one (for example if there's only test1 but not test 2)

Comment: This is kinda abusing CSS. Ideally this kind of functionality should be accomplished with JavaScript as even the slightest change to your document's structure will invalidate your CSS selectors and render this 'feature' broken.

Comment: @Dai I disagree. Using sibling selectors and pseudo-classes are an excellent way to circumvent the requirement of JS for very simple functionalities such as this. Also, this is way more efficient that JS, which requires several more lines and bytes (binding click/change event handlers, toggling classes or changing inline styles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `+` is an immediate sibling selector. `.test2` is not the immediate sibling of the checkbox, it is a general sibling. Therefore, try using `~` instead. Also, you forgot the `.` prefix for classes — your code is targetting the *elements* `<test1>` and `<test2>` instead of elements with the classes `test1` or `test2`.

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .test1{
    background: #5BC0DE;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .test2{
    background: #000000;
}
```

Fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/eYgdm/346/

In fact, to future proof your setup where you might add additional elements between the checkbox and `.test1` or `.test2`, I recommend using the general sibling selector instead ;)

p/s: You can read more about siblings selectors in this excellent writeup: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Thank you so much. Is this possible for more than 2 elements ? (what you use then ~ , + or what ? ) Thank you again

Comment: `~` is a *general* sibling element, i.e. it will work for all siblings downstream (no limits), regardless of their distance away from the selected element. `+` is for immediate sibling, i.e. the sibling element that is after the selected element (therefore only one will be selected).